# Proving $\int^c_0 xf(x)\,dx=(c-1)\int^c_0 f(x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $$\int^1_0 xf(x)\,dx = \int^1_0 f(x)\,dx.$$
> Prove that exists a $c\in(0,1)$ such that
> $$\int^c_0 xf(x)\,dx=(c-1)\int^c_0 f(x)\,dx.$$

I tried to apply the Mean Value Theorem but I did no get to any point.

Comment: I think you have typed something incorrectly. The thing I see is to find a $c$ such that $(c-1)t=t$ for a $t\in\mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: As written, the only possible solutions are $c=1$ and $c=2$, and they must be rejected. The problem statement is probably wrong.

Comment: Just check it out it's clearly typed wrong. Both sides of the claim are $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{c}{xf(x)}dx$

Comment: No,I write something wrong.I corrected it now.

Comment: Are you sure it's correct? Also, can you show us your attempt with the MVT?

Comment: Let $g(t)=\int_0^t xf(x)dx$ and $F(t)=\int_0^tf(x)dx$. Then $g'(t)=tF'(t)$, together with $g(1)=F(1)$, implies that $$\int_0^1 F(x)dx=0.$$ Then $F$, being continuous, is either identically $0$ or not. If it is identically $0$, then so is $f$ and so is $g$. Then $g(c)=(c-1)F(c)$ is satisfied for all $c$. Thus, we have that $f$ cannot be identically a nonzero constant. Hopefully this helps

Comment: where did you find this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $$F : x \mapsto \int_0^x f(t)dt$$

By hypothesis, one has
$$F(1)=\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx= \int_0^1 xf(x) \,dx= \int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x) \,dt \,dx = \int_0^1 \int_t^1 f(x) \,dx \,dt$$ $$= \int_0^1 F(1)-F(t) \,dt = F(1)-\int_0^1F(t)\,dt$$

(you can also make this calculation with an integration by parts on $\int_0^1 xf(x) \,dx$).

So you deduce that
$$\int_0^1 F(t) \,dt = 0$$

Now let $$G : x \mapsto \int_0^x F(t) \,dt, \quad \quad \text{and }\quad h : x \mapsto e^{-x}G(x)$$

Because $G(0)=G(1)=0$, then $h(0)=h(1)=0$, so by Rolle's theorem, there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $h'(c)=0$. And one has
$$h'(x)=e^{-x}\left(G'(x)-G(x) \right)$$

so you get $c \in (0,1)$ such that $G'(c)=G(c)$, i.e. such that
$$F(c)=\int_0^c F(t) \,dt$$

You deduce that
$$\int_0^c xf(x) \,dx = \int_0^c \int_0^x f(x) \,dt \,dx = \int_0^c \int_t^c f(x) \,dx \,dt = \int_0^c F(c)-F(t) \,dt =cF(c)-F(c)$$

i.e. that
$$\int_0^c xf(x) \,dx = (c-1)\int_0^c f(x)\,dx$$